# Is it possible to build a standalone HTML5 App *without* bundling a browser?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, electron, chromium

Solutions such as Electron require bundling an entire browser with the resulting `.app` build, which causes it to have several gigabytes even for a single hello world app. Most users already have Chrome installed on their computers, though. Is it possible to create a standalone `.app` application which uses the existing browser to open itself, hiding the frames / URL bar of the browser, and has access to system resources (fs, child processes, etc.)?

Edit: I'm thinking something on the lines of *"bundle node.js + an HTML into a .app which opens an existing browser (pointing to that HTML) without the URL bar".* Node.js can then access the filesystem and communicate with the App via HTTP, WS, etc. The only real problem here is opening Chrome without the URL bar, I guess.

Comment: There are Chrome Apps...

Comment: [An HTML5 webapp?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 woops! Completely forgot to add that I need access to the `filesystem`, etc. Otherwise, of course, a simple HTML5 file is almost an answer (other than the "no URL bar" part).

Comment: There is React Native which does what you want, but I have only used it on mobile platforms. I know [it works on desktop platforms](https://www.microsoft.com/reallifecode/2016/05/26/creating-universal-windows-apps-with-react-native/) as well but haven't tried it. It doesn't use HTML5 though because it would be slow. It uses only ES7.

Comment: Is the app really standalone if it still makes use of the system browser to run, though?

Comment: Not really, I agree @BoltClock, but it would be really nice, for example, shipping without chromium, avoiding 50gb of download, checking if it is there and, if it isn't, dynamically downloading it.

Comment: My Electron apps are @ 100-150 mb. Seems very reasonable to me

Comment: 100mb? How? I thought the hello world itself was much more

Comment: @NoGrabbing depends on what you do with the ignore options on packaging and bundling of your application.. If you for example save every dep as a real "dependency" and not "devDependency" electron packages them all.. There are plenty more things to do to optimise it

Answer (score 0):

I saw [nodekit](https://github.com/nodekit-io) which is an attempt to use the JavaScript engine already available on each platform.

So for example on Mac it'll probably use `WKWebView` and on Windows 10 it'll run on the JavaScript Universal apps platform.

For most though, only having to test on electron makes developing apps much simpler and you can have a fully functional app in an installer under 40MB.